# Am I escaping the strings incorrectly in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, escaping, syntax-error

I am trying to create a clickable link in javascript

```
var content = '<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"displayContent(\"TEST\")\">Whatever</a>';

$("#placeHolder").html(content);
```

but I keep getting an error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

Is that not the correct way to escape double quotes and create a link?

Comment: There's code missing here. There are no } characters in the code sample you've provided.

Comment: Seems the cause is out of the scope of this snippet.

Comment: You're escaping the double-quotes correctly at the very least

Comment: @ceejayoz, it is most likely in the context of a function, but I also think there is relevant code missing.

Comment: As @AdamRackis' answer shows, it's the `"` around the `TEST` argument. The `onclick` is going to end up looking like `onclick="displayContent("TEST")"` instead of ``onclick="displayContent('TEST')"``.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need to escape the single quotes

```
var content = '<a href="#" onclick="displayContent(\'TEST\')">Whatever</a>'
```

As bozdoz says:

> You escape single quotes that are within single quotes; you escape double quotes that are within double quotes

---

But why not do

```
var content = $("<a />").attr("href", "#").text("Whatever").click(function(){
     displayContent('TEST')
});
```

Or as Nathan says:

```
var content = $('<a href="#">Whatever</a>').click(
     function() { displayContent('TEST') 
});
```

Comment: To add to this: you escape single quotes that are within single quotes, you escape double quotes that are within double quotes.

Comment: @bozdoz - I couldn't say it better myself, so I didn't try.  See edit - thanks and +1

Comment: That seems to work but if I replace it to ("TEST") I get the same error? WHy is that

Comment: One reason not to do that is that building an element in this fashion is actually more expensive than creating the whole definition in one string. That being said, it's preferable to assign a click handler with JS instead of HTML. A good trade off would be: `var content = $('<a href="#">Whatever</a>').click(function(){
     displayContent('TEST')
});`

Comment: @CodeCrack - because then you'd have html like this:  `<a href="#" onclick="displaycontent("TEST")"`  - see how the double quotes around the onclick are interfering with the double quotes around TEST?

Comment: @Nathan - I don't think the performance would be noticeable, but I definitely think your version is cleaner

Comment: I think we answered a question today exactly like this with exactly the same type of answers :D

Answer (score 2):

You can avoid that mess by creating elements like this:

```
var content = $( "<a>", {
    href: "#",
    text: "whatever",
    click: $.proxy( displayContent, 0, "TEST" )
});
```

Comment: $.proxy - I'll have to look that one up  +1 :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$.proxy(displayContent, null, 0, "TEST");` otherwise won't 0 (unsuccessfully) try to get set to `this`?

Comment: @AdamRackis the first argument is the function, second is context (`0` is shorter to write than `null`) and the rest are curried arguments. The currying was added in 1.6 I think, it's not even documented. The native `Function#bind` always curried arguments as well so it was kinda strange `$.proxy` didn't at first.

Comment: Ahh.  I understood about the currying (and I love function.bind) - I just didn't realize you could pass 0 as null like that.  Cool.  (and why **isn't** that documented)

Comment: @AdamRackis passing `0` as context is not same as null, it will be converted to a `Number` object  to be `this` once the function is called in non-strict mode and remains a primitive in strict mode. `null` is `window`/`null` in non-strict/strict.

Comment: Interesting.  When I was messing around with $.proxy I tried passing a string like "Hello" as the context, but that blew up.  I assumed you couldn't set `this` to a primitive, but then I tested `bind` and it works with anything.  I think there's some quirkiness with proxy

Comment: Ahh - proxy has another overload that takes a string - got it

Answer (score 1):

You only need to escape quotes when they are the same type as used by your opening and closing quotes. In your example, you are unnecessarily escaping double quotes because your string is wrapped in single quotes. That being said, because of the double quotes in `onclick` statement the parser will have issues with the the call to `displayContent()`.

Try this, instead:

```
var content = '<a href="#" onclick="displayContent(\'TEST\')">Whatever</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to escape them at all!

```
var content = '<a href="#" onclick="displayContent(\'TEST\')">Whatever</a>'; 

$("#placeHolder").html(content);
```

Just have it like that, as you don't need to escape `"` usually, when in embeded in a `'`;

But you do need to escape `'` characters when it is a parameter in a function.

Comment: This won't work (you have used double quotes for the parameter to `displayContent` as well as the `onclick` attribute value).